# Boost.Serialize error for vector<complex>

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, vector, complex-numbers

I am trying to use the default serialization facilities with boost, but I didn't manage to serialize a complex vector. I tried this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>

using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> type;

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, vector<type>& objs, const unsigned version) {
    ar & objs;
}

int main(){
    vector<type> r;
    r.push_back(1.3);
    r.push_back(12.12);
    r.push_back(-31.05);

    ofstream ofs("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa & r;
    return 0;
}
```

which compiles fine but crashes on execution. Yet if I do

```
typedef double type
```

then everything works OK. I can't figure out a solution for that. Any help?

Thanks,

Jan

Comment: Please do not do that "#define type complex<double>" - better is typedef complex<double> type;

Comment: @DieterLücking You are right of course, but I just threw a fast code to put some emphasis on the difference between the behaviour for double and complex<double>.  Somehow, it looked more explicit this way when I wrote it - now I don't know why I thought that.

Comment: Btw: the code works fine. The output file contains: "22 serialization::archive 9 0 0 3 0 1.3 0 12.119999999999999 0 -31.050000000000001 0"

Comment: Hmmmm... in that case it may have to do with my setup. I use a pre-compiled version of boost for VS 2012. I guess that's a no-no, I will have to compile it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I thought that was it, however I tried on a different computer, where I compiled boost myself, and all I get is an empty file. So I wonder, @DieterLücking, did you compile my test code with Visual C++ 2012, or was it something else, perhaps GCC? Because it could be a boost bug.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

Comment: That may be it then. The out-of-the-box install for VS2012 of boost 1.54 does not work properly for this case, it seems. Time to tell the boost people I guess. Thank you Dieter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap up and mark as answered:

The problem seems to be with the boost 1.54 implementation for Visual Studio 2012, since the g++ version of the code is reported to work correctly. Thanks to @DieterLücking for testing my code and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

lol - rather than saying:

The problem seems to be with the boost 1.54 implementation for Visual Studio 2012, since the g++ version of the code is reported to work correctly.

I would say:

The problem seems to be with Visual Studio 2012, since the g++ version of the code is reported to work correctly.

Rbert Ramey